# What's the next step in this Unequal (Futoshiki) puzzle?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

I'm currently stuck on [this puzzle](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/unequal.html#6de#999219787311854) from Simon Tatham's website (he calls it "Unequal", although the standard name according to Wikipedia is [Futoshiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futoshiki)). My progress so far is:

[image: partially solved grid]

I've even tried a few "what if" conditions (assuming another cell is filled in a particular way, and seeing what can be deduced from there), but I haven't managed to deduce enough to fill in any more cells for sure. What am I missing?

Comment: Would it be a good idea to briefly explain the rules of Futoshiki here?

Comment: @Brandon_J I included links to two sources which explain the rules, and anyway the question is unlikely to be solved by anyone not already familiar with the rules.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the second column and try to place the 6.

> Row 1/4 - cannot be 6 since row already has a 6.
>  Row 1/3/5/6 - cannot be 6 since number must be less than another digit.
>  Therefore, 6 must go in row 2.

This leads to some immediate deductions in the right-most column, and the whole solution follows by the usual rules of the puzzle.

*If you still want to solve the puzzle yourself, **do not view the next spoiler!***

> The final grid should look like this:
>
>  [image]

Comment: Thank you! I checked your first spoiler and then managed to solve the rest. Annoying how simple it seems now ... just something I hadn't checked properly in what I'd thought was a thorough scan. (It would have worked even before placing the top 6, which was the last number I put in before getting stuck.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor No worries :) Futoshiki can do that to you! I often think the difficulty in this puzzle type really comes from the vast amount of white space in front of you - with something like a Sudoku you normally have more numbers in other squares to help you make the right logical leaps - when you're relying on the symbols *between* the number squares it's somehow much harder to process what you're seeing, because you're really not seeing very much!